# Running update query using Python cx_Oracle simply makes the system hang and no exception generated

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, cx-oracle

Trying to run update query but it simply stand still without any output

can someone please look into the below code that I have written and check where it is getting wrong. The same query works fine when trying manually with Oracle SQL Developer.

````
query = """update PRODUCTNAMES set SHORT_TEXT_VALUE = :1 where UID in 
        (select UID from PRODUCTUID where PID in
        ('ab12','ed90','bv78') AND LOCALIZED_ATTRIBUTE_KEY = :2)"""
con = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password,
                                    host/service)
cursor = con.cursor()                                   

cursor.execute(query,['CARRY,EASY','WearableSubtype'])
con.commit()
cursor.close()
con.close()```
````

Comment: Find your session in v$session or use monitor session feature in SQL Developer and you'll probably see the lock/wait that Littlefoot indicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you ran it in SQL Developer and **did not commit**, then that session holds those rows **locked** and won't let you update them through your Python script.

First commit (or, rather **rollback**) in SQL Developer, and then run Python script.